# How can I access model fields linked to another model In Model.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following model Schedule, Booking and RoutePrice.

Schedule Model:

```
class Schedule(BaseModel):
    bus_company_route = models.ForeignKey(BusCompanyRoute, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    travel_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    seat_discounted_price_for_travel_agent = AmountField(null=True, blank=True)
    seat_discounted_price_for_user = AmountField(null=True, blank=True)
    seat_discounted_price_for_foreigner = AmountField(null=True, blank=True)
    representative_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    seat_price_for_travel_agent = AmountField(null=True, blank=True)
    seat_price_for_user = AmountField(null=True, blank=True)
    seat_price_for_foreigner = AmountField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And Schedule is Linked to BusCompany Route in Many to One Relation.
So BusCompany route model is.

```
class BusCompanyRoute(BaseModel):
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    shift = models.ForeignKey(
        Shift,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    journey_length = models.TimeField(null=True)
    bus_company = models.ForeignKey(BusCompany, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

and BusCompanyRoute is linked with Route Price in One to many Relation.
RoutePrice Model is as.

```
class RoutePrice(BaseModel):
    bus_company_route = models.ForeignKey(BusCompanyRoute, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    bus_type = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    seat_price_for_travel_agent = AmountField(null=True)
    seat_price_for_user = AmountField(null=True)
    seat_price_for_foreigner = AmountField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I want to get `seat_price_for_travel_agent` in schedule 'save method()' From `RoutePrice` Model I have come upto here. How shall I get `seat_price_for_travel_agent` from `RoutePrice` in Schedule?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    seat_price_for_travel_agent = self.bus_company_route.routeprice_set
```

Now I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved!

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.seat_price_for_travel_agent = self.bus_company_route.routeprice_set.get(). \
        seat_price_for_travel_agent
    self.seat_price_for_user = self.bus_company_route.routeprice_set.get().seat_price_for_user
    self.seat_price_for_foreigner = self.bus_company_route.routeprice_set.get(). \
        seat_price_for_foreigner
    super(Schedule, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```